# using CDO.message.HTMLBody within MSScriptControl.ScriptControl object

Tags: vbscript, cdo.message, msscriptcontrol

In a c-ish language, I was instantiating a MSScriptControl.ScriptControl object and using the .AddCode method to run VBScript, which in turn, instantiated the CDO.Message object.

However, every time I got to the 
`"objMsg.HTMLBody = \"" + email_body + "\" \n"`
(note this was in the c, the VBScript would be:
`objMsg.HTMLBody = email_body`
line of the code, I got an error

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error : Unterminated string constant

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found the problem was that the variable `email_body` contained character 10 (`\n`) in it (several places), which was interpreted in VBScript as the end of a line of code (but before a close-quote), which is a syntax error.

I can't imagine I'm the only person to miss this, so I'm writing a little 'knowledge base' here.

Resolution:
In the parent-language (in this case, a weird form of c called hsl), use a string-replace method to replace all inctances of `\n` with `<br>` and it works just fine now, such as:
`StrReplace(email_body, "\n", "<br>"`

then call the `ScriptControl.AddCode( ... );` method.